# My page CSS is broken in IE8, why? Trying to figure out what I have done wrong

Tags: css

One of my pages css seems to be a little broken in IE8. I thought if I added clear:both the problem would have been fixed but the elements are still...well please, see for yourself:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"A little broken" is not a technical description.

IE8 is not aware of HTML5 elements so you cannot style them like a modern browser. You need to add the HTML5 shiv which is javascript that will inform IE8 of those elements and allow you to style them. As it sits, any CSS styling you give things like `article` will be ignored.

Just copy this into the head of your page to see what happens:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>  
<script src='http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js'></script>  
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: they dont have styling applied.

Comment: @Damian - You mean `header` and `nav` and all the rest don't either? If nothing else, they get `display:block` applied to them automagically by the browser. Otherwise, what is their purpose? Why are you using them at all? IE8 will ignore them.

Comment: @Damian - Please note the script I added to my answer.

Comment: Adding the shiv fixes the layout for this page for me as well

Comment: @Rob indeed but other browsers wont ignore them so I keep them for semantic purposes. All other objects such as header and nav dont have styling. I just dont understand why the aside part is broken. Is it because of the display? There is no need for shiv either because they dont have styling applied

Comment: @Damian - Browsers automatically applies `display:block` at a minimum to all those elements which will affect the flow. IE8 ignores it altogether and those elements will not affect the flow as in the other browsers. This could be the cause of all your issues. Trying the code I show is easy enough to try.

Comment: Rob is right and it's also the `figure` tag that is breaking the layout; the `float: left` and `display: block` never get applied - edited, sorry about the confusion

Comment: @Rob Sorry if I sound a little dumb. So you say all browsers apply diplay:block and that it causes the issue in ie8 or..sorry..I just like to learn.

Comment: @Damian The issue is (actually we don't know for sure yet) IE8 does not allow the HTML5 elements to affect the normal flow while all other browsers will. It's like stacking blocks on top of each other but IE8 doesn't see some of those blocks and things come tumbling down.

Comment: @Rob I understand. I will try shiv right now and let you quickly know how it went. I think I will upload it too

Comment: @Rob I noticed a stray end tag.

Comment: @Rob hey it worked. Thank you for your explanation. I included HTML shiv.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 tags (header, article, figure) don't work correctly in IE8, you would have to include a html5 shiv (it is bundled in [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/)) between the head tags.
There is also a stray `</div>` on line 213 (see [html validation](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://rolfvohs.com/composer.php))

Comment: as for the html5 tags, they dont have styling applied. All other sites work. It seems to me this issue has to do with the aside element. Very weird though. I created a extra div for the styling. The aside tag is only for semantic purposes